# Microsoft Edge listed twice in default apps

Tags: windows-10, file-association, microsoft-edge

I have Microsoft Edge listed twice in my Windows 10 default apps and one of the entries has no icon. Is there any way of fixing this, or at least figuring out why it's listed twice (either via the registry or a tool)?

[image: Microsoft Edge listed twice in default apps]

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using exactly and have you installed all cumulative updates?  The second entry seems to suggest you have not installed the cumulative update that removes Legacy Edge.

Comment: The second entry may point to the old version of Edge before Microsoft adapted Chromium for Edge. Therefore this may be a relic of this version that no longer exists.

Comment: Updating to V21H1 should fix it. Also run (from an Admin command prompt) DISM and SFC and Restart;   dism.exe  /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth followed by SFC /SCANNOW  and restart.

Comment: In order to clean up the menu I would need to know, the exact actions, required to get it on my own screen.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. I'm using 21H1 and I tried running the dism and sfc commands, but unfortunately they didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The second Edge icon is missing, which might indicate it refers to an old (non-Chrome) version of Edge that has been removed already.

If you click on that second shortcut, and Edge does not start, you might get a dialog stating,"The item 'Edge' that this shortcut refers to has been... Do you want to delete this shortcut?" Click "Yes," and it should be gone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you're confusing the default apps drop-down entries with a typical Windows shortcut (.lnk files).